# Why is my perlin noise implementation looking so blocky?

Tags: javascript, p5.js, perlin-noise

I started to do my own implementation of perlin noise in javascript (using p5js), but the results are not really what I expected:[Perlin noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGpoT.png)

Here's my code:

```js
let grid, spacement;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);

  spacement = 20;
  
  //initialize gradient vectors grid
  grid = createGrid(width / spacement, height / spacement);

  background(255);

  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  for (let i = 0; i < width; i++) {

    for (let j = 0; j < height; j++) {
      let nearbyPoints = getNearestPoints(i, j);

      let distanceVectors = getDistanceVectors( nearbyPoints[0], nearbyPoints[1], nearbyPoints[2], nearbyPoints[3],i, j)

      let correspondingVectors = getGradientVectors(nearbyPoints[0],nearbyPoints[1],nearbyPoints[2],nearbyPoints[3]);

      let dots = [];

      for (let d = 0; d < 4; d++) {
        let dotProduct = getDotProduct(distanceVectors[d],correspondingVectors[d]);

        dots.push(dotProduct);
      }

      let sx = i- nearbyPoints[0]*spacement
      let sy = j-nearbyPoints[2]*spacement
      let ix0 = interpolate(dots[0], dots[1], sx)
      let ix1 = interpolate(dots[3], dots[2], sx)
    
      let finalValue = interpolate(ix0,ix1,sy);
      
      stroke(map(finalValue, -10, 10, 0, 255));

      point(i, j);
    }

  }

  console.info(`All points have found their distance vectors! (${width * height} points)`);

  console.info(`All points have found their matching gradient vectors! (${width * height} points)`);
}

//creates a grid of points to which are assigned random 2D vectors
function createGrid(amountX, amountY) {
  let array = Array(amountX);

  for (let i = 0; i <= amountX; i++) {
    array[i] = Array(amountY);

    for (let j = 0; j <= amountY; j++) {
      
           array[i][j] = p5.Vector.random2D()
           console.log(mag(array[i][j].x,array[i][j].y));
          
    }
  }

  return array;
}

//gets the 4 points of the grid created earlier that are the nearest to a x,y point
function getNearestPoints(x, y) {
  let x1 = Math.floor(x / spacement);

  let x2 = x1 + 1;

  let y1 = Math.floor(y / spacement);

  let y2 = y1 + 1;

  return [x1, x2, y1, y2];
}

//gets the vectors assigned to the nearest points
function getGradientVectors(x1, x2, y1, y2) {
  let topLeft = grid[x1][y1];

  let topRight = grid[x1][y2];

  let bottomLeft = grid[x2][y1];

  let bottomRight = grid[x2][y2];

  return [topLeft, topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft];
}

//get the distance vector between a x,y point and the four nearest points
function getDistanceVectors(x1, x2, y1, y2, x, y) {
  let topLeft = [x - x1 * spacement, y - y1 * spacement];

  let topRight = [x - x2 * spacement, y - y1 * spacement];

  let bottomLeft = [x - x1 * spacement, y - y2 * spacement];

  let bottomRight = [x - x2 * spacement, y - y2 * spacement];

  return [topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight];
}

//gets the dot product of the distance vector and the gradient vector
function getDotProduct(v1, v2) {
  v1 = createVector(v1[0], v1[1]);

  v2 = createVector(v2.x, v2.y);

  let dot = p5.Vector.dot(v1, v2);

  return dot;
}

//interpolates between a0 and a1, based on the weight w
function interpolate(a0,a1,w){
  
return  (a1-a0)*(3.0-w*2.0)*w*w+a0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.6.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

My main reference is the wikipedia perlin noise page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise).

I first thought that the error was in the interpolation function, so I tried a lot of different functions, but nothing really looks right. I'm quite lost, and I can't figure out where my mistake is.

Thanks a lot for your time and attention, I apologize for any language mistake, english isn't my mother tongue.

Comment: Would cheating be acceptable in this case? By cheating I mean - apply Gaussian blur to what you have, right before the image is generated. If not, have you considered lowering the `spacement` to 1 (and adapting the rest of your code), to create a larger grid?

Answer (score 2):

The main problems were that you didn't normalize some values to be between 0 and 1 so your code was calculating HUGE values for the noise. as those were almost always bigger than 255 or smaller than 0, Your noise was in black OR white and not in black and white. The other big problem is that some indices/values were swapped. That's what caused the incoherences between the different cells.

Anyways, here is my modified and commented version of your code :

```js
let grid, spacement;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(256, 256);

  spacement = 64;
  
  //initialize gradient vectors grid
  grid = createGrid(width / spacement, height / spacement);

  // forces some values of the grid for tests
  /*
  grid[0][0] = createVector(sqrt(2), sqrt(2));
  grid[1][0] = createVector(-sqrt(2), sqrt(2));
  grid[0][1] = createVector(sqrt(2), -sqrt(2));
  grid[1][1] = createVector(-sqrt(2), -sqrt(2));
  */
  
  background(255);

  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  for (let i = 0; i < width; i++) {

    for (let j = 0; j < height; j++) {
      let nearbyPoints = getNearestPoints(i, j);

      let distanceVectors = getDistanceVectors( nearbyPoints[0], nearbyPoints[1], nearbyPoints[2], nearbyPoints[3], i, j)

      let correspondingVectors = getGradientVectors(nearbyPoints[0], nearbyPoints[1], nearbyPoints[2], nearbyPoints[3]);

      let dots = [];

      for (let d = 0; d < 4; d++) {
        let dotProduct = getDotProduct(distanceVectors[d], correspondingVectors[d]);

        dots.push(dotProduct);
      }

      let sx = i / spacement - nearbyPoints[0] //sx and sy needed to be normalized
      let sy = j / spacement - nearbyPoints[2]
      let ix0 = interpolate(dots[0], dots[1], sx)
      let ix1 = interpolate(dots[2], dots[3], sx) // and not interpolate(dots[3], dots[2], sx)
    
      let finalValue = interpolate(ix0,ix1,sy);
      
      finalValue = map(finalValue, -1, 1, 0, 255); //the range of this noise is [-sqrt(2); sqrt(2)] not [-10; 10] but you can lower this to [-1; 1] without too much risk of overflow
      
      // the next line is a substitute to the previous one. It does the mapping between 0 and 255 but also increases the contrast (the 8 is the contrast parameter and can be changed). another advantage is tha it will not overflow
      
      //finalValue = 255 / (1 + exp(-8 * finalValue));
      
      stroke(finalValue);

      point(i, j);
    }

  }

  console.info(`All points have found their distance vectors! (${width * height} points)`);

  console.info(`All points have found their matching gradient vectors! (${width * height} points)`);
}

//creates a grid of points to which are assigned random 2D vectors
function createGrid(amountX, amountY) {
  let array = Array(amountX);

  for (let i = 0; i <= amountX; i++) {
    array[i] = Array(amountY);

    for (let j = 0; j <= amountY; j++) {
      
           array[i][j] = p5.Vector.random2D()
          
    }
  }

  return array;
}

//gets the 4 points of the grid created earlier that are the nearest to a x,y point
function getNearestPoints(x, y) {
  let x1 = Math.floor(x / spacement);

  let x2 = x1 + 1;

  let y1 = Math.floor(y / spacement);

  let y2 = y1 + 1;
  
  return [x1, x2, y1, y2];
}

//gets the vectors assigned to the nearest points
function getGradientVectors(x1, x2, y1, y2) {
  let topLeft = grid[x1][y1];

  let topRight = grid[x2][y1]; // 1 and 2 were swapped

  let bottomLeft = grid[x1][y2]; // here too

  let bottomRight = grid[x2][y2];

  return [topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight]; // bottomRight and bottomLeft were swapped
}

//get the distance vector between a x,y point and the four nearest points
function getDistanceVectors(x1, x2, y1, y2, x, y) {
  // those vectors needed to be normalized
  let topLeft = [x / spacement - x1, y / spacement - y1];

  let topRight = [x / spacement - x2, y / spacement - y1];

  let bottomLeft = [x / spacement - x1, y / spacement - y2];

  let bottomRight = [x / spacement - x2, y / spacement - y2];

  return [topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight];
}

//gets the dot product of the distance vector and the gradient vector
function getDotProduct(v1, v2) {
  v1 = createVector(v1[0], v1[1]);

  v2 = createVector(v2.x, v2.y);

  let dot = p5.Vector.dot(v1, v2);

  return dot;
}

//interpolates between a0 and a1, based on the weight w
function interpolate(a0,a1,w){
  
return  (a1-a0)*(3.0-w*2.0)*w*w+a0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.6.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
```